# Is authentication required for apps that uses AWS APIs?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm currently trying to use the Amazon Rekognition API to develop a mobile app that detects texts from a book then uses the result to search the reviews on Google. However, most of the AWS sites that I've been reading documentation says to add an authentication and access control system. Do every apps that use the AWS API use the authentication/credentials system from the ? If so, how would I implement it into this app? I wasn't planning to have any login systems the app.

If my understanding is wrong, can anyone point that out for me, I'm still unfamiliar of API usages and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Access Keys acts as the authentication for the API calls.

First, you need to create an IAM user with Rekognition permission and create an access key for that user. [For more about creating an access key](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)

Then, you can use that access key to authenticate with AWS API and make a request to Rekognition. [For more about Rekognition API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Reference.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see, so if I'm understanding this correctly, IAM users are basically for employees/managers/admins for the app, while the customers don't have to necessarily sign up for anything.

Comment: From your description above, I can say Yes. After you configure the aws access keys in your application, you don't need your customers to necessarily sign up.